# How to fill a text field with item selected from a dropdownlist with jQuery in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

I'm working on a small customized survey. The Index View is populated with questionList from the database so basically I have a list of questions from the database displayed on the view. The question list now has a dropdown list for each question. The challenge is getting to populate an empty text field with the value for each question and summing up the various values based on the item value selected from each question.

Below is the view to the index action

```
@model IEnumerable<WorkPlaceBullying.Models.Question>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Survey Questions";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Questions</h2>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <p>We don't have any Questions yet!.</p>
}

@Html.ActionLink("Question", "New", "Question", "", new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Question", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover ">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>ID</td>
                    <td>Questions</td>
                    <td>Category</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            @foreach (var question in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@question.Id</td>
                    <td>
                        @*@Html.ActionLink(@question.SurveyQuestion, "Edit", "Question", new { id = @question.Id }, null)*@
                        @question.SurveyQuestion
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @question.QuestionCategory.QuestionCat
                    </td>
                    @if (@question.QResponseCategory.Id == 1)
                    {
                        <td>
                            @*@Html.Hidden("Weight", @question.ResponseCategoryId)*@
                            @Html.DropDownList("Weight", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.ResponseId, "Select Response", new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="text" id="Weight" name="__Weight" class="form-control col-sm-2" value="">
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
}
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Weight").change(function (evt) {
                $('input[name=__Weight]').val($("#Weight").val());
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

I succeeded in getting the value of selected item into the text field but it's populated on all the fields. How do I make each text field unique and have it's own selected value?

Below is the graphical view 
[image]

From the above image...the weight of the item selected in question 1 is 2. When items are selected for the other questions...it doesn't reflect in the textbox but rather...it reflects the value of the weight for question 1 on all the text boxes.

Comment: You obviously have a jQuery issue. Why on earth are we wading through asp to try to help you? Please click the `<>` snippet editor. Copy enough HTML and JavaScript to make a [mcve] and remove all the asp

Comment: @mplungjan The jQuery is at the Section scripts portion of the html code. This is razor mind you. Let me add razor. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need unique IDs

Right now it seems your code is copying the value of the field with ID="Weight" to the field named __Weight  - they look to be the same field -

But why the copying? Why not sum on the selects and not have the empty field?

Anyway here is an example using HTML as I guess it might look - which does not care about names - I added a class to your selects instead:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".weightSel").on("change",function (evt) { 
    $(this).closest("td").next().find("input").val(this.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>

      SurveyQuestion
    </td>
    <td>
      QuestionCat
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="weightSel">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="__Weight" class="form-control col-sm-2" value="">
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>

      SurveyQuestion
    </td>
    <td>
      QuestionCat
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="weightSel">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
      </select>

    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="__Weight" class="form-control col-sm-2" value="">
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Id</td>
    <td>
      SurveyQuestion
    </td>
    <td>
      QuestionCat
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="weightSel">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="__Weight" class="form-control col-sm-2" value="">
    </td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Please what do you mean with this line of code // use ".sel" if you can give it a class? I did the copying because I don't know jQuery. It's a language I'll have to learn.

Comment: I use $("select") which is any select - if you add "sel" to the class if the select you can use $(".sel") for the selects or some other class name

Comment: so the final code would look lik so

        $(function () {
            $(".sel").on(change, function (evt) {
                $(this).closest("td").next().find("input").val(this.value);
            });
        });

Comment: So i need to give .sel a class

Comment: Yes if you have class="sel ...." on the select (the ... are any other class names already there

Comment: This is more confusing. please could you help with the lines of code? i got errors using what you sent. This is what I have:

        $(function () {
            $("sel").change(function (evt) {
                $(this).closest("td").next().find("input").val(this.value);
            });
        });

Comment: I do not know the syntax of your server code. I have updated with a working example - you can see the select needs a class I can use to select. If there are NO other selects on the page that in the table, you can leave out adding the class and use the tag selector `$("select")` instead of `$(.weightSel")`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148821/discussion-between-guzzyman-and-mplungjan).

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly ,
in Jquery you can use children() and parent() and find() methods after you choose the selector . you may add index attribute to each row or using something like this   ==>
after you select the selector of the value 
    $(this).parent().find('td').children('input').val();

Comment: 1: This is a comment - please answer more questions and you will have rep to comment 2: Your example is wrong. Please see my answer for the correct access to the parent TD and the input. Your code tries to find a TD as a child of a parent TD - the .parent().find)'td') does not work